# Iptables: route ntp requests from lan to internal vpn server

Tags: networking, vpn, lan, iptables, nat

i have to following config

```
   client                  gw with openvpn                 ntp server
192.168.10.82 ----> eth0 192.168.10.1 - tun0 10.8.0.46 ---> 10.8.0.1
```

where i can't install openvpn client on .82

I would like that .82 ask for ntp to 192.168.10.1,
192.168.10.1 will route the question to 10.8.0.1 through its tun0 interface 10.8.0.46
and then will reply back to .82

Below my iptables config

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jan  3 22:29:42 2021
*filter
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
# Accept traffic from internal interfaces
-A INPUT ! -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
# Accept traffic with the ACK flag set
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK ACK -j ACCEPT
# Allow incoming data that is part of a connection we established
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# Allow data that is related to existing connections
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Accept responses to DNS queries
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1024:65535 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
# Accept responses to our pings
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
# Accept notifications of unreachable hosts
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
# Accept notifications to reduce sending speed
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type source-quench -j ACCEPT
# Accept notifications of lost packets
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
# Accept notifications of protocol problems
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jan  3 22:29:42 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jan  3 22:29:42 2021
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jan  3 22:29:42 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jan  3 22:29:42 2021
*nat
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# eth0 to 4g dongle
-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

trying the following lines don't work:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 123 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.1:123
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -p udp --dport 123 -d 10.8.0.1 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.46
```

any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Is `192.168.10.1` the default gateway on `192.168.10.82`? If there's no specific route for `10.8.0.1` (or any subnet that covers it), perhaps you should simply set it as the NTP server and save the `DNAT`.

Comment: 192.168.10.1 is the default gw for local network but traffic is not routed all through vpn, and i don't want this.

Comment: Well, I didn't ask you to route all traffics through the tunnel, but set `10.8.0.1` as NTP server on `192.168.10.82`. Anyway, have you enabled IP forwarding at all? (Has it *been working as a router* for any traffics yet?)

Comment: ip forwarding on 192.168.10.1 yes, but i can't install openvpn on 192.168.10.82 . how it can see 10.8.0.1 ?

Comment: It doesn't need to. If you have no specific route for `10.8.0.1` on `192.168.10.82`, traffics for the destination will go via its default (that's what default means) gateway anyway, which is `192.168.10.1`.

Comment: ok, and on 192.168.10.1 iptables rules are correct?

Comment: Both of the rules seem fine to me, but since it's not working, saving (as in, skipping) the DNAT may help you isolate the problem for a bit.

Comment: 10.8.0.1 as ntp server for 192.168.10.82 and removed DNAT, doesn't work

Comment: Try `sudo tcpdump -ni any udp port 123` on the gateway and see if it tells you what's going on?

Comment: 18:44:46.673652 IP 192.168.10.82.48960 > 10.8.0.1.123: NTPv4, Client, length 48


repeated multiple times till it fails

Comment: What if you trigger NTP on the gateway? (With `10.8.0.1` as the server)

Comment: it works, works for all 10.8.0.0/24
 ntpdate 10.8.0.1
    18 Apr 18:54:36 ntpdate[6203]: adjust time server 10.8.0.1 offset -0.007540 sec

Comment: tcpdump on ntp server when running ntpdate on gtw : 
18:54:30.329186 IP 10.8.0.46.123 > 10.8.0.1.123: NTPv4, Client, length 48
18:54:30.329438 IP 10.8.0.1.123 > 10.8.0.46.123: NTPv4, Server, length 48

Comment: It seem like the gateway is not forwarding the traffics. I have no idea if it really has the `net.ipv4.ip_forward` sysctl set to `1` and its iptables `filter/FORWARD` chain really has policy of `ACCEPT` and has no (`DROP`/`REJECT`) rules. (Otherwise you should be able to witness the `SNAT` occuring in the `tcpdump` output, IIRC.)

Comment: on gtw: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Comment: Sorry, I mean I have no more ideas if those are really the case.

Comment: and no drop/reject rules on filter/FORWARD

Comment: Maybe you can try `--to-source 10.8.0.46:123`, just in case I was wrong about `tcpdump` and something peculiar is happening here...

Comment: don't work :( running the same tcpdump on 10.8.0.1 and nothing happens. doesn't reach the ntp server

Answer (score 0):

1st reply of Tom Yan is the solution, the discussion after it is due to my fault editing the wrong iptables config file.